# Using Enum.reduce, why that compiler "error undefined function my_func/0"

Tags: elixir, reducers

My code is below, and it's not clear for me why I have the compiler complaining:

```
rle.exs:3: warning: function reducer_fun/2 is unused
** (CompileError) rle.exs:15: undefined function reducer_fun/0
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1337: :lists.foreach/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
```

Namely that supposes that Enum.reduce is expecting a reducer function of arity 0, which completely puzzles me.

Is there something obviously false in my code ? Why doesn't it use the defined reducer_fun ?

```
  defp reducer_fun(x,y) do y end

  @spec encode(String.t) :: String.t
  def encode(string) do
    cond do
      string == "" -> ""

      # the reduction is done here
      true -> Enum.concat(Enum.reduce(string, {:no_letter, 0, []}, reducer_fun))
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
true -> Enum.concat(Enum.reduce(string, {:no_letter, 0, []}, reducer_fun))
```

should be

```
true -> Enum.concat(Enum.reduce(string, {:no_letter, 0, []}, &reducer_fun/2))
```

as `Enum.reduce/3` expects a `fn` with arity 2 as the third argument, while your original code is trying to call a function in the same module named `reducer_fun` with no arguments (hence the error `undefined function reducer_fun/0`) and pass the returned value to `Enum.reduce/3`.

Edit: also, Strings aren't enumerable. You should pass the string to `String.to_char_list`, `String.codepoints`, or `String.graphemes` first to convert it into a list. The exact function to use depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Odd... I thought Strings weren't Enumerable? Trying a reduction over a string in iex (`1.3-dev`) gets me `protocol Enumerable not implemented for "abcd"`

Comment: are you sure the arrity is 3 for the fn ? I think it's 2.

Comment: @StephaneRolland Agreed. On the docs (http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3), I see both reduce/2 and reduce/3 take an arity-2 fun.

Comment: @StephaneRolland sorry, that was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: @CodyPoll you're right. indeed now at runtime it complains `protocol ENumerable not implemented for "MyStringTest"`  , but at first I was stuck with the compilation error.

Comment: @StephaneRolland Ah, strings aren't enumerable. You probably want to convert it to a list using `String.to_char_list`, `String.codepoints` or `String.graphemes` depending on what you're trying to do.